# is there anyway to do Date math in HQL

Tags: hibernate, date, hql

I have looking for solution but found nothing. What i want to achive is translate this SQL to HQL :

```
SELECT * FROM `penyewaan` p WHERE NOW() between p.tanggal_sewa and DATE_ADD(p.tanggal_sewa, INTERVAL p.lama_sewa DAY)
```

I found nothing similar to MySQL's DATE_ADD() in HQL. 
As you can see, it would be funny I think, to evaluate it first in Java then pass it through parameter.

Any sugestion how i can achive my goal?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't exists DATE_ADD equivalent function in HQL.

You can:

Extend your sql dialect or you can use another field date on your table and use an operator <= or >=